# Running through if/else statement and getting lost

Tags: php

I'm having a brain dead moment and getting lost in my logic, please can someone help!

I'm looking to recreate 3 scenarios:

1. If downloads AND resources exist.
2. If only downloads exist.
3. If only resources exist.

These are decided by the two statements:

Downloads = `have_rows('downloads')`

Resources = `get_sub_field('resources')`

How can I run through the 3 scenarios in an if/else loop?

Comment: Maybe you can edit your title if/else is not a loop it's a control structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$downloads = have_rows('downloads');
$resources = get_sub_field('resources');

if($downloads && $resources) {
  // do something
} elseif($downloads) {
  // do something else
} elseif($resources) {
 // yet another something else
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood your question

```
if(have_rows('downloads') && get_sub_field('resources'))
{
//some stuff
}
else if(have_rows('downloads'))
{
//Some other stuff
}
else if(get_sub_field('resources'))
{
//More stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this???

```
$bDL = have_rows('downloads');
$bRE = get_sub_field('resources');

//  If downloads AND resources exist.
if ($bDL && $bRE){

}

// If only downloads exist.
if ($bDL && !$bRE){

}

// If only resources exist.
if (!$bDL && $bRE){

}
```

Comment: I know, but readability is much better. I avoid nested if/then/else/elseif's whenever possible.

Comment: nested if meaning is a little bit different from what you have mentioned. nested if's are those which are actually "nested inside" other if's and I agree, in this case it could be not very good practice [http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Comment: Yes, but even a few if's isn't that bad (programmers can read that easily). Personally I just like to read an if-statement, almost as if it was plain English. Matter of taste I guess.